# Image onClick event attribute React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I wanted to add `onClick` attribute to the image dynamically. But the click event didn't work.

//Code

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
  
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlContent,
      "text/html"
    );
 
    const imageData = doc.querySelectorAll("img");

 imageData.forEach((x: any) => {
     
            htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(
                x.outerHTML,
                '<img width="240" height="160" style="cursor: grab; margin: 10px;" src="' +
                  x.getAttribute("src") + '"onClick={() => setOpen(true)}/>'
              );
          });
```

Tried,

```
onClick={handleClick(true)}

const handleClick = (flag: boolean) => {
      setOpen(flag)
  }  

onClick={setOpen(true)}

onClick={() => ' +setOpen(true) + '}

x.addEventListener('onClick', () => setOpen(true));
```

**htmlContent:**

```
<p>new test <img src="https://i.imgur.com/7KpCS0Y.jpg%22" width="100" height="100" id="img_1665468977463_0"></p><p>new new test <img src="https://i.imgur.com/7KpCS0Y.jpg%22" width="100" height="100" id="img_1665468986873_0"></p><p>next level test <img src="https://i.imgur.com/7KpCS0Y.jpg%22" width="100" height="100" id="img_1665468996237_0"></p><p></p><p>format test</p><ol><li><p>one</p></li><li><p>two </p></li><li><p>three</p></li></ol>
```

Can i get any help?

Comment: what is imageData that you're looping over? could you add a sample of the actual html content?

Comment: @SiddharthSathe Updated the question, please check

Comment: How are you rendering your HTML content? Using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

Comment: @Slbox just as `<Typography>parse(dangerouslySetInnerHTML)</Typography>`

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper div outside the htmlcontent in the HTML markup which should not be replaced and attach event listener to that div

```html
<div id="wrapper" onClick={handleOpen(true)}>
  //your HTML content
  {htmlContent}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you share the whole code for htmlContent, it can help us to find a solution.
Anyway, please try as follows:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  if(document.querySelector('.img-item')) {
    document.querySelector('.img-item').addEventListener('click', () => {
      setOpen(true)
    })
  }
}, [htmlContent])


imageData.forEach((x: any) => { 
  htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(
      x.outerHTML,
      '<img className="img-item" width="240" height="160" style="cursor: grab; margin: 10px;" src="' +
        x.getAttribute("src") + '"/>'
    );
});
```

Comment: Shared the HTML content. Please take a look

Comment: How did you define the variable htmlContent? using state?

Comment: No, that's passed as a param into the method. Something like,  `const handleImages = (htmlContent: string) =>{}`

Comment: the html content doesn't have any image with img-item class name, so this  won't work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the `onClick` you could pass an `id`/look for the existing one, and then **once you mount** your `htmlContent` (I'm guessing that's the plan) you can:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  document.getElementById('id').addEventlistener('click', setOpen(true));
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `click` event in JavaScript doesn’t have the `on` that’s in its HTML and JSX equivalents, so try:

```
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll(‘img’)
imgs.forEach(x => {
  x.addEventListener('click', () => setOpen(true))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since dangerouslySetInnerHTML is being used to render the html, you won't be able to call on your react component functions through onClick event attribute.

Instead you can set up event listeners on your images once they are rendered by using useEffect hook.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let imageData = document.querySelectorAll("img");

    imageData.forEach((i) => {
      i.outerHTML = i.outerHTML.replace(
        i.outerHTML,
        '<img width="240" height="160" style="cursor: grab; margin: 10px;" src="' +
          i.getAttribute("src") +
          '">'
      );
    });

    imageData = document.querySelectorAll("img");

    imageData.forEach((i) => {
      i.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setOpen();
      });
    });
  }, []);
```

Here is an example on codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/clickableimages-8qtjh5?file=/src/App.js:153-671